# 3D convolutional autoencoder is not returning the right output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to use an autoencoder on spatiotemporal data.
My data shape is: `batches , filters, timesteps, rows, columns`. I have problem with setting the autoencoder to the right shape.

This is my model:

```py
input_imag = Input(shape=(3, 81, 4, 4))

x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(input_imag)
x = MaxPooling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv3D(8, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv3D(4, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same', name='encoder')(x)

x = Conv3D(4, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
x = Conv3D(8, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
decoded = Conv3D(3, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_imag, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

autoencoder.summary()
```

This is the summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3, 81, 4, 4)]     0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d (Conv3D)              (None, 16, 81, 4, 4)      2176
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3D) (None, 16, 27, 2, 2)      0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, 8, 27, 2, 2)       5768
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3 (None, 8, 9, 1, 1)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)            (None, 4, 9, 1, 1)        1444
_________________________________________________________________
encoder (MaxPooling3D)       (None, 4, 3, 1, 1)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)            (None, 4, 3, 1, 1)        724
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling3d (UpSampling3D) (None, 4, 9, 2, 2)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)            (None, 8, 9, 2, 2)        1448
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling3d_1 (UpSampling3 (None, 8, 27, 4, 4)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)            (None, 16, 27, 4, 4)      5776
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling3d_2 (UpSampling3 (None, 16, 81, 8, 8)      0
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_6 (Conv3D)            (None, 3, 81, 8, 8)       2163
=================================================================
Total params: 19,499
Trainable params: 19,499
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

What I should change to have the decoder output shape as  `[?,3,81,4,4]` not `[?,3,81,8,8]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the MaxPooling3D and UpSampling3D operations to be symmetrical (at least in terms of output shapes). Let's look at the input shape of the last MaxPooling3D layer:

```
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)            (None, 4, 9, 1, 1)        1444
_________________________________________________________________
encoder (MaxPooling3D)       (None, 4, 3, 1, 1)        0
```

The shape is `(None, 4, 9, 1, 1)`. The last two dimensions are already 1, so they can't be divided by 2, as specified in `pool_size`. So MaxPooling3D layer, despite having a `pool_size=(3, 2, 2)`, effectively does an operation with `pool_size=(3, 1, 1)`. At least I think that is what happens under the hood.

I'm a bit surprised there is no error or warning when specifying pool_size greater than input size.

To fix that you can set the first UpSampling3D layer's shape to `(3, 1, 1)`

```
x = UpSampling3D((3, 1, 1), data_format='channels_first')(x)
```

So, the complete solution:

```
input_imag = Input(shape=(3, 81, 4, 4))

x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(input_imag)
x = MaxPooling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv3D(8, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv3D(4, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same', name='encoder')(x)

x = Conv3D(4, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling3D((3, 1, 1), data_format='channels_first')(x)
x = Conv3D(8, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((3, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
decoded = Conv3D(3, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_imag, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

autoencoder.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 3, 81, 4, 4)]     0         
                                                                 
 conv3d_14 (Conv3D)          (None, 16, 81, 4, 4)      2176      
                                                                 
 max_pooling3d_4 (MaxPooling  (None, 16, 27, 2, 2)     0         
 3D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv3d_15 (Conv3D)          (None, 8, 27, 2, 2)       5768      
                                                                 
 max_pooling3d_5 (MaxPooling  (None, 8, 9, 1, 1)       0         
 3D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv3d_16 (Conv3D)          (None, 4, 9, 1, 1)        1444      
                                                                 
 encoder (MaxPooling3D)      (None, 4, 3, 1, 1)        0         
                                                                 
 conv3d_17 (Conv3D)          (None, 4, 3, 1, 1)        724       
                                                                 
 up_sampling3d_6 (UpSampling  (None, 4, 9, 1, 1)       0         
 3D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv3d_18 (Conv3D)          (None, 8, 9, 1, 1)        1448      
                                                                 
 up_sampling3d_7 (UpSampling  (None, 8, 27, 2, 2)      0         
 3D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv3d_19 (Conv3D)          (None, 16, 27, 2, 2)      5776      
                                                                 
 up_sampling3d_8 (UpSampling  (None, 16, 81, 4, 4)     0         
 3D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv3d_20 (Conv3D)          (None, 3, 81, 4, 4)       2163      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 19,499
Trainable params: 19,499
Non-trainable params: 0
```