# 3D convolutional autoencoder with odd or even width and height

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to use an autoencoder to encode spatiotemporal data.
My data shape is: `batches , filters, timesteps, rows, columns`. where rows=columns

For each data set I have different size for the last 2 dimensions. For example, for dataset 1 the rows and columns are 5X5, for dateset 2 they are 4X4.

I have problem with setting the autoencoder to the right shape to be used across the different datasets.

I have posted this question while I was testing on a dataset which has 4 rows and columns in the data shape. : [3D convolutional autoencoder is not returning the right output shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401193/3d-convolutional-autoencoder-is-not-returning-the-right-output-shape)

However, this architecture doesn't work when the rows and columns is any number other than 4.

For the encoded sequence I want the codes to ​maintain the length of the time-steps dimension the same and reduce the height and the width to size 1 .
How to provide a 3D convolutional auto-encoder that can work properly with different input shapes in terms of rows and columns in this case?

This the working example when rows and columns are 4:

```
input_imag = Input(shape=(11, 81, 4, 4))


    x= input_imag
    x = Conv3D(64, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv3D(32, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)

    x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    encoded = MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same', name='encoder')(x)
    
    x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
    x = UpSampling3D((1, 1, 1), data_format='channels_first')(x)
    x = Conv3D(32, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
    x = Conv3D(64, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
    decoded_out = Conv3D(3, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_imag, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Model summary:

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 map_inputs (InputLayer)     [(None, 11, 81, 4, 4)]    0

 conv3d (Conv3D)             (None, 64, 81, 4, 4)      31744

 max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3D  (None, 64, 81, 2, 2)     0
 )

 conv3d_1 (Conv3D)           (None, 32, 81, 2, 2)      92192

 max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 32, 81, 1, 1)     0
 3D)

 conv3d_2 (Conv3D)           (None, 16, 81, 1, 1)      23056

 encoder (MaxPooling3D)      (None, 16, 81, 1, 1)      0

 conv3d_3 (Conv3D)           (None, 16, 81, 1, 1)      11536

 up_sampling3d (UpSampling3D  (None, 16, 81, 1, 1)     0
 )

 conv3d_4 (Conv3D)           (None, 32, 81, 1, 1)      23072

 up_sampling3d_1 (UpSampling  (None, 32, 81, 2, 2)     0
 3D)

 conv3d_5 (Conv3D)           (None, 64, 81, 2, 2)      92224

 up_sampling3d_2 (UpSampling  (None, 64, 81, 4, 4)     0
 3D)

 conv3d_6 (Conv3D)           (None, 11, 81, 4, 4)      31691

=================================================================
Total params: 305,515
Trainable params: 305,515
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

We can us use `None` in `Input` for dynamic sizes and resize to the original shape in the end. The output image size in the original encoder is approximately equal to the input size. We just have to fine-turn it slightly.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import UpSampling3D, MaxPooling3D, Conv3D


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        input_imag = Input(shape=(11, 81, None, None))

        x = input_imag
        x = Conv3D(64, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)
        x = Conv3D(32, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(x)

        x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        encoded = MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first', padding='same', name='encoder')(x)

        x = Conv3D(16, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
        x = UpSampling3D((1, 1, 1), data_format='channels_first')(x)
        x = Conv3D(32, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = UpSampling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
        x = Conv3D(64, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
        x = UpSampling3D((1, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(x)
        decoded_out = Conv3D(3, (5, 3, 3), data_format='channels_first', activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

        self._autoencoder = Model(input_imag, decoded_out)
    
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        output = self._autoencoder(inputs, training=training)
        resized_output = self._resize(output=output, input_shape=input_shape)

        return resized_output
        
    def _resize(self, output, input_shape):
        output_shape = tf.shape(output)
        reshaped_output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[-1, output_shape[3], output_shape[4], 1])
        resized_output = tf.image.resize(reshaped_output, [input_shape[3], input_shape[4]])
        output = tf.reshape(resized_output, shape=[output_shape[0], output_shape[1], output_shape[2], input_shape[3], input_shape[4]])
        return output
    
    
model = MyModel()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

print(model(tf.zeros(shape=[2,11,81,4,4])).shape)   # (2, 3, 81, 4, 4)
print(model(tf.zeros(shape=[2,11,81,5,5])).shape)   # (2, 3, 81, 5, 5)
print(model(tf.zeros(shape=[2,11,81,42,42])).shape) # (2, 3, 81, 42, 42)
```